# Raising an array of numbers to a power in SAS

Tags: arrays, matrix, sas, exponent, sas-iml

I need to raise every number in an array (a column in a SAS dataset) to a certain power. I've been told that this can be done in IML, after writing the contents of the column to a matrix. However, a matrix must apparently be square to be raised to a power in IML, and my data are very much **not** a square matrix. What is the procedure and the syntax for raising one column of numbers to a power?

Sorry for asking about such simple things, I'm as new to SAS as can be.

Comment: I understand I should probably have said "range" instead of "array".

Comment: @Stu's answer below is correct.  If you are in IML and attempt Mat**2, then you are attempting a matrix multiplication (Mat x Mat, or Mat squared).  You wanted an element-wise, whose operator is #.  So Mat##2 will do an element wise power.

Answer (score 3):

No need to apologize. SAS is a very different thought process that takes a lot of practice. You're asking all the right questions.

SAS is an iterative language. The array of numbers you are speaking of sounds like many individual observations within a dataset. SAS performs operations on values one row at a time within each dataset, then moves onto the next row once it hits the bottom of a data step.

Assuming your dataset looks like this:

```
 var
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

If you wanted to square each number, you would create a new variable (or you can overwrite the current variable, your choice) and use the `**` exponent operator.

```
data want;
    set have;
    var_squared = var**2;
run;
```

In this step, SAS creates a dataset `want`, reads the dataset `have`, creates a new numeric variable of length 8 named `var_squared`, assigns it a value of `var*var`, then outputs. It repeats the read-calculate-write cycle for each row until it hits the end of file marker. Note that `output` is implied automatically. When you do not specify `output`, SAS will automatically write to the new dataset once it hits `run`.

Your new dataset will look like this:

```
var var_squared
1   1
2   4
3   9
4   16
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try doing this and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, the SAS/IML language provides many more types of multiplication and "raise to power" operations than the familiar scalar operations.  You can read about [different ways to multiply in the SAS/IML language.](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/05/20/matri-multiplication.html)

For most operations, the SAS/IML language distinguishes between [elementwise operations and vector or matrix operations](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/68150/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_langref_sect028.htm). For your use case, you should use the elementwise power operator (##) which will raise each element of a vector or matrix to a power.  For example, to compute the square of the height of each student in a data set, you can use:

```
proc iml;
use sashelp.class;
read all var {"Height"};
close sashelp.class;

sqHt = Height##2;   /* raise each element to 2nd power */
print Height sqHt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I used the elementwise operator, and it worked (the software did not object this time), although another issue arose (about which I'll ask in a separate question).